# Scrapy on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, web-crawler, scrapy

I"m getting these error when i create a scrapy project. I already went through all the google links and it just wont work out for me on ubuntu 14.04

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 122, in execute
    cmds = _get_commands_dict(settings, inproject)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 46, in _get_commands_dict
    cmds = _get_commands_from_module('scrapy.commands', inproject)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 29, in _get_commands_from_module
    for cmd in _iter_command_classes(module):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 20, in _iter_command_classes
    for module in walk_modules(module_name):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 68, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/bench.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scrapy.tests.mockserver import MockServer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/tests/mockserver.py", line 6, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import reactor, defer, ssl
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/ssl.py", line 59, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 11, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding
```

Some say do pip install pyOpenSSL==0.13 i get the following

```
   OpenSSL/crypto/x509.h:17:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory

 #include <openssl/ssl.h>

                         ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `libssl-dev` package:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```